# Which one is better to use when fetching from the datastore: key or id?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

My mind is still impregnated with SQL thoughts... i'm used to retrieve from the database using the id as the main key, but in App Engine i'm unsure whether i should favor one over the other.
What is recommended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about the App Engine generated id, it is effectively the same as using the key.  A key is just an encoded version of the kind, namespace, and id or name.

[Model.get_by_id simply](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_get_by_id) converts the id to a key before fetching the entity.